# Parse Function Error in Two Digit date

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime, datetimepicker

Friends..

My System date format is MM/dd/yyyy.

I would like to get format dd/MM/yyyy. and i m using folling code

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(stdate.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
```

and pass dt in datetime format(dd/MM/yyyy) to query

this code gives correct output  for single digit date (like 1/6/2023) //stdate is DateTimePicker

but give error in two digit name(Like 28/8/2013)

what is wrong here...Friends help me..

Note-I Have set datetimepicker format as custom and fustomFormat is dd-MM-yyyy..From DateTimepicker Properties.
     so my datetimepicker control shows value 01/08/2013..but actual value in datetimepicker's properties is 8/1/2013 (28/08/2013....in properties 8/28/2013)

Comment: `TryParseExact` is solution

Comment: `stdate.Value` is a `DateTime` which doesn't depend on system format, system datetime format is just affect the `ToString` which converts a `DateTime` to a string to display. So your code in fact does nothing, it's the same to `DateTime dt = stdate.Value;`. **Unless you want to swap month and day** in the `stdate.Value`.

Comment: Plz..convert this code in TryParseExact.

Answer (score 0):

just doing

```
     DateTime dt = dateTimePicker1.Value;

     string str = dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

will get you the date you want in the format u need

if you get date in string format and want to convert it to DateTime you can use:

```
    DateTime dt;
    CultureInfo enUS = new CultureInfo("en-US");
     string dateString = "05/01/2009";

     if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, "dd/MM/yyyy", enUS,
                                DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
     {
        dateTimePicker1.Value = dt;
     }
```

Comment: Thnks for Reply..But See you convert date in string..and i want to find data beetween two dates so..can string format work here...??

Comment: @TusharWakchaure wait wait wait, you want the difference between two dates?

Comment: @TusharWakchaure you can compare directly like `dateTimePicker1.Value > anotherDateTime` or difference like `var diff = dateTimePicker1.Value -anotherDateTime;

Comment: @Damith i think he needs the difference, now which is bigger

Comment: But dateTimePicker1.Value give system date format MM/dd/yyyy,But in My datbase dates store in dd/MM/yyyy Format..So i Will have to convert date format

Comment: @TusharWakchaure so you are getting values from database as strings and want them as DateTime, right?

Comment: Yes..Actually i m getting dates from two datepicker from search form and convert them in dd/MM/yyyy and compare them with database dates

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because although you formatted the `stdate.Value` into the string format you wanted, `DateTime.Parse` still uses the system format `MM/dd/yyyy`.

And while `DateTime.TryParse` may help with what you want to do, the result will be `dt == stdate.Value`, which just leads you back to square one.

What you probably want to do is to format `stdate.Value` only at the time when you want to put it into your query, which I assume requires a string input